# rails 4: param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two form as below

```
<%= form_for(@customer) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

second form

```
<%= form_tag(customers_path, {:multipart => true, :method => :post } ) do%>
  <%= submit_tag I18n.t('views.import_customers_submit') %>
<% end%>
```

Both form hit create action of Customer controller. And in create action it just save the `@customer` object.

White listed parameters are

```
def customer_params
  params.require(:customer).permit(:name)
end
```

Now the problem is when I submit my first form I do not get any error. But when I submit second form I get this error

```
param is missing or the value is empty: customer
```

And the error points to the white list method

```
def customer_params
  params.require(:customer).permit(:name)
end
```

I understand this is because, for the first form the params are being submitted as params[:customer][] but for the second form this is not maintained. So how can I make this work for second form. In second form all I do is to import a file.

Comment: Please add the rails development log for this specific request also ..

Comment: Well, with form_tag, you need to manually write all input fields with a wrapper like `text_field_tag "customer[name]",.. ` .. then all values will come under the root key `customer` as `params: { .. customer: {name: 'someone'}..}`. With `form_for` the same thing is done by rails ..

Comment: You are correct, but how can I solve this?

Comment: show your form_tag conent, I will tell you. Or, use different white filtering like params.permit. By checking the condition if the root key is present or not. There are too many solutions.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your form_tag doesn't seem to have any @customer data in it.

The `customer_params` method in your control is expecting customer[name] to be sent in the post payload.

Include something like `<%= text_field_tag(@customer.name) %>` and it should work.

Details -> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#a-generic-search-form

Comment: wrong answer. With `form_tag`, data will come inside the `params` directly. OP didn't show the actual content of the `form`, but I am quiet sure, OP's input are not wrapped in the root key as I have shown in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, I hope it works for you.

```
<%= form_tag(customers_path(:name => @customer.name), {:multipart => true, :method => :post } ) do%>
  <%= submit_tag I18n.t('views.import_customers_submit') %>
<% end%>
```